# How to join a list of names in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

This has to be an easy question, but I cannot figure out how to create a list of names separated by commas without having a trailing comma at the end.

So here is my code...

```
    For Each u In users
        userList.Append(u.FirstName)
        userList.Append(" ")
        userList.Append(u.LastName)
        userList.Append(", ")
    Next
```

This creates a list, but it always looks likes this:

**James Smith, Chris Williams, Zoey Babcock,**

How do I get generate a list without an extra comma at the end?

Thanks

Here is the working code thanks to all the help:

```
    Dim fullNames = (users.Select(Function(u) u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName))
    Dim userList As String = String.Join(", ", fullNames)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make CSV from list of string in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758850/make-csv-from-list-of-string-in-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**LINQ**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763068.aspx) to project each user into a collection of full names, then use [**`String.Join()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to join them using a separator of your choice.

```
List(Of String) fullNames = From u _
                            In users _
                            Select (u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)
String userList = String.Join(", ", fullNames)
```

You can express the LINQ query like this as well. It is identical to the above:

```
List(Of String) fullNames = _
                users.Select(Function(u) u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)
String userList = String.Join(", ", fullNames)
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen code like this before...what is this style called and what does this code do?  - thanks -

Comment: It's called LINQ as in Language INtegrated Query and can do some neat tricks. I Updated my answer and added a link.

Comment: great, I've heard of it before but didn't realize it was so powerful.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
For i as integer = 0 to users.Count - 1
    userList.Append(String.Format("{0} {1}", users(i).FirstName, users(i).LastName))
    If (i + 1) < users.Count - 1
        userList.Append(", ")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ and `Join` is the best answer when it is available, but otherwise you should be using `StringBuilder` and then it is easiest to leave your code as it is, with the following final line:

```
If userList.Length > 0 Then userList.Length -= ", ".Length
Return userList.ToString
```