# Converting List<string> to csv using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

I have a list that I generated with a text file. I'm going through the list and using StringBuilder so I can use the StringBuilder object to create a csv file. The file has a ^ when its starting on a new record. I need to be able to append a new line to the stringbuilder object when the List returns a string that has the ^ in it, but as you can see with my code below, I can never tell when to append the new line and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is one of the ways I tried and the issue shows in the comments

```
foreach (var a in lstData)
        {
            if (a.Contains("^"))
            {
                string strName = Regex.Replace(a, "<.*?>", string.Empty).Remove(0, 1);

                sbQ.Append(strName + ",");
            }
            else
            {
                sbQ.Append(a + ",");
            }
            if (a.Contains("^")) sbQ.AppendLine();

            // Doesn't work, always appendlines when it encounters '^'
            // should only append new line on next occurence

        }
```

and here is the other way.

```
        string strZ;
        string strX;
        foreach (var a in lstData)
        {
            if (a.Contains("^"))
            {
                strZ = Regex.Replace(a, "<.*?>", string.Empty).Remove(0, 1);
                sbQ.Append(strZ + ",");
                strX = strZ;
            }

            if (strZ == strX)
            {
                // Causes Error : Use of Unassigned local variable 'strX'
            }
        }
```

I've tried using a do/while statement by iterating through a copy of the List and didn't work either.

**EDIT**

The data in the text file looks like this..

```
^<a class= ........>Name</a>
value1
value2
value3
value4
etc....
^<a class=......>Name</a>
value1
value2
value3
value4
etc....
^<a class=......>Name</a>
etc...
```

What I am trying to accomplish

```
name, value1, value2, value3, value4, etc...
name, value1, value2, value3, value4, etc...
```

**EDIT**
Results in csv.

[image]

Where you see the link, that had a ^ before it and when that gets reached then it should move on to line 2, then when it hits the ^ again to line 3 and so forth. Its a new record when it hits the ^

This is how it should look...

[image: What I am trying to get it to look like]

**EDIT/UPDATE**

```
Physician Name, (CPSO#)
Primary Practice Location
Disciplinary Info  &amp; Restrictions
^Aal Ali, Saleh Saif Salem A S Fares (#82358)
P O Box: 8313
Abu Dhabi 0000
United Arab Emirates
Phone: +971506117644
^Aalders, Ryan Francis (#103559)
Kingston General Hospital
Department of Family Medicine
76 Stuart Street
Kingston ON  K7L 2V7
Phone: (613) 533-9300
^Aarabi, Mehdi (#81281)
UHN Toronto Western Hospital
2nd Floor East Wing
399 Bathurst Street
Toronto ON  M5T 2S8
Phone: (416) 603-5641
^Aaron, Shawn David (#62311)
Ottawa General Hospital
501 Smyth Road
Ottawa ON  K1H 8L6
Phone: (613) 737-8899 Ext. 74729
Fax: (613) 739-6807
```

Comment: What is `lstData`?  Is it the string that contains `a,b^c,d`?  You want to split on `^` and then `,`?  Are there any considerations for escape characters?  Is what you want just `lstData.Split('^').Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray()`?  i.e. return an array of string arrays where each array contains an array of the comma separated fields?

Comment: @KirkWoll, Sorry, yes lstData is the textfile data I put into a List<string>. The text file data isn't comma separated, each value is on a new line. I'm taking the data and adding it to a string builder and separating it.

Comment: So you just want `x.Split(`^`)`?  Sorry, I'd post that as an answer, but I'm still not 100% of your requirements.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I'll edit the question and be more specific...

Comment: What's wrong with string.Join?

Comment: @emodendroket, I'm new to manipulating data this way, I'm used to databases

Comment: @Chris `string.Join(",", list.Select(i => string.Concat("\"", i.Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\"")))` probably does what you need.

Comment: @emodendroket, I'll try it out right now.

Comment: @emodendroket, I got the same result as I did with Noctis' answer. Its all separated into its own cells but all is one line one in the csv

Comment: still not sure what you mean chris, can you put your output you get from mike's and my answer, vs what you want?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I missed the part about matching ^.  You can just insert a line break when you see that character but it won't fit in one line anymore.

Comment: @emodendroket, I just added a new pic of how I am trying to get it to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works, and will deal with ^'s appearing in the data as well (other than as the first character of a line)

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
using(var file = File.AppendText("NewFile.txt"))
foreach (var csv in text.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine+"^", "\n^"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine, "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .Select(sublines => string.Join(",", sublines.Select(s => s.ToString()))))
{
    file.WriteLine(csv);
}
```

See this fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uyHppL

And, here's a variation that doesn't use a foreach, which should be a little more efficient as it only writes to the file once.

```
var csv = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine+"^", "\n^"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine, "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .Select(sublines => string.Join(",", sublines.Select(s => s.ToString()))));

using(var file = File.AppendText("NewFile.txt"))
    file.WriteLine(csv);
```

Comment: That was close, it is separating it at the ^, but then below it is the values and not appearing like the pic that I added to get it to look like, I know it wasn't tested :)

Comment: @Chris - What?  I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Chris - Since you aren't showing us what the actual data is, we can only guess, and you will have to make any changes that are different from what our guess would be.  My code assumes each line ends in a \r\n, if it's only \n then it needs to change to that.  Show us the ACTUAL csv in text form (not data in a spreadsheet) and confirm the line ending type.

Comment: I did show what the data looks like, its in the edits above. Noctis and emodendroket comments and solutions, put it to a csv file (its in the first pic where you see everything on one line), the 2nd pic is how I am trying to get it to look.

Comment: @Chris - I said "in text form" and "not data in a spreadsheet"

Comment: There must be some confusion, and I apologize if its me, but I don't have a csv file of the data yet, I'm trying to create one with a list. I read a file that I created into a list, I need to create a csv that goes into a spreadtsheet from the list and the escape character to tell me its a new record and put it on another line..Its possible that I am going around it the wrong way and making it more difficult than it should be. I'll edit the question and add some of the data that is being read from the file into a list...

Comment: @Chris - As you can see from this dotnetfiddle, it looks good to me.  I added a TrimEnd() to remove the trailing comma on each line, but other than that it works as expected.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/uyHppL

Comment: @Chris - I modified it slightly to work with both types of line endings, perhaps that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so very much, I been working on trying to figure this out all day,literally. My testing page is full of commented code that I wrote trying to get this figured out, its a mess. I had to just tweak the code a bit and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Chris - you also have a problem of an embedded comma in your first column.  So you'll have to put quotes around that column for Excel to load it into a single cell.

Comment: That's not the only problem I am going to encounter, I just noticed as I looked farther down the csv that there is a part that shows if the doctor works at other locations and provides that info as well. My next step was to put all the data into a datatable so I can use it easier with a gridview, that was going to be easy because I thought it was straightforward until I noticed the other details lol. The plan was to take the data from the text, place it into a datatable then write it to a csv file.

Comment: @Chris - I made a slight improvement that deals with situations where there is a ^ character within your text.  The new code only accepts a ^ character at the beginning of a line... It also has the side-effect of no longer needing to trim the newline at the end, As you can see by looking at the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could use LINQ to build the list. See the following:
[Make CSV from list of string in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758850/make-csv-from-list-of-string-in-linq)

Comment: I searched through a lot of links and missed that one

Answer (score 1):

You can make a helper method that add the newline when it hits a carrot. File.ReadLine will make break on newline then we can just replace out the carrot in the helper method and do the data scrubbing you want.  Then use String.Join to combine all the results back with a comma.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var text = File.ReadLines(@"YourFile.txt");

    var lines = ParseList(text);

    using (var file = File.AppendText(@"NewFile.csv"))
    {
        file.Write(String.Join(",", lines));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> ParseList(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var newline = Regex.Replace(line, @"<.*?>", String.Empty);
        if (newline.StartsWith("^"))
        {
            // change carrot to newline
            newline = Environment.NewLine + newline.Remove(0, 1);
        }
        yield return newline;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work :

```
List<string> list = 
    new List<string>{"^one","two","^three","four","f1","f2","^five","six","s1","s2"};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var element in list)
{
    if (element.Contains("^")) {
        sb.Append("\r\n" + element.Replace("^",""));
    }
    else  {
        sb.Append("," + element);
    }
}
var result = sb.ToString();
```

It outputs:

> one,two
>   three,four,f1,f2
>   five,six,s1,s2

You might want to have your html parsing in there

Comment: When I run this, and have the result saved to a csv file, all the data is separated into cells but its all on line 1, and moving on two line 2, line 3, etc...when it hits the next ^

Comment: I'll edit and add a pic of the results when I open it...The ^ is a delimiter and when that gets hit then that's the start of a new record and should be on line 2, line 3 etc..one second

Comment: I just added a new pic of how I am trying to get it to look